# string undeclared identifier in class

Tags: c++, class

I am learning c++ inheritance and here I have a problem.
if I make this simple code all in main.cpp file it will works without any 
problem.

but when I seperate the files in header file and else
it won't work and it gives me some errors.

here is the code of header file named book.h

```
 #ifndef BOOK_H
 #define BOOK_H

 class book
{
 private:
 string name;

 public:
 book(string n = "default") : name(n) {};
 ~book() {};
 void printname();
};

#endif
```

and here is the code of book.cpp that I defined the function of this class
in this file.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include "book.h"

using namespace std;

void book::printname()
{
 cout << name << endl;
 return;
}
```

and finally the main.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h> 
#include <string>
#include "book.h"

using namespace std;

 int main()
{
 system("color 0A");
 book programing("c++");
 cout << "the name of the book is ";
 programing.printname();

 system("pause");
 return;
}
```

and the errors that I get:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>
> Error C2065   'name': undeclared identifier   book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.cpp    10
>
> Error C3646   'name': unknown override specifier  book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  7
>
> Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int   book    d:\vs program\book\book\book.h  7
>
> Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  10
>
> Error C2065   'n': undeclared identifier  book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  10
>
> Error C2614   'book': illegal member initialization: 'name' is not a
>   base or member    book    d:\vs program\book\book\book.h  10
>
> Error C3646   'name': unknown override specifier  book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  7
>
> Error C4430   missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not
>   support default-int   book    d:\vs program\book\book\book.h  7
>   Error C2061   syntax error: identifier 'string'   book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  10
>
> Error C2065   'n': undeclared identifier  book    d:\vs
>   program\book\book\book.h  10
>
> Error C2614   'book': illegal member initialization: 'name' is not a
>   base or member    book    d:\vs program\book\book\book.h  10

and other errors...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to make sure that `string` is a valid type in the .h file.

1. Add `#include <string>`.
2. Use `std::string` instead of just `string`.

---

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <string>

class book
{
   private:
      std::string name;

   public:
      book(std::string n = "default") : name(n) {};
      ~book() {};
      void printname();
};

#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54002233/8968475) appears to address your question.
As a side note, since C++11, you can also specify default values for class members. So you could just do this instead:

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <string>

class book
{
   private:
      std::string name = "default";

   public:
      book() = default;
      book(std::string n) : name(n) {};
      ~book() {};
      void printname();
};

#endif
```

Comment: In this code the default value will never be used, as you don't have a default constructor (and the provided one replaces it)

Comment: I like the addition, however, you didn't explain where the actual issue was

Comment: You need to add a default constructor:  `book() = default;`