# How to use strings in a class c++

Tags: c++, string

I am having trouble using string variables inside of a class in c++. I have tried using include but that doesn't appear to have any noticeable effect.
Here are the contents of the header file the class is declared in:

```
#include <string.h>

#ifndef STUDENT_H
#define STUDENT_H

class Student
{
private:
    int iStudentAge;
    int iStudentBirthDay;
    int iStudentBirthMonth;
    int iStudentBirthYear;
    string sStudentName;
    string sStudentCourse;
public:
    Student();
    Student(int iValue1, int iValue2, int iValue3, int iValue4, string sValue5, string sValue6);
    void setAge(int iNewValue);
    int getAge();
    void setBirthDay(int iNewValue);
    int getBirthDay();
    void setBirthMonth(int iNewValue);
    int getBirthMonth();
    void setBirthYear(int iNewValue);
    int getBirthYear();
    void setName(string iNewValue);
    string getName();
    void setCourse(string iNewValue);
    string getCourse();
};

#endif // !STUDENT_H
```

The specific errors I am having are all on the lines that involve strings, except for the include line.

Comment: `string` is in the `std` namespace, so write it as `std::string` (everywhere except in the include).

Comment: There is also `using namespace std` but it's considered bad practice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice

Comment: Please include the error message in the quesiton

Comment: Does this answer your question? [string undeclared identifier in class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54002183/string-undeclared-identifier-in-class)

Answer (score 6):

`<string.h>` is the C header file for string handling null-terminated byte strings. `std::string` is defined in the header file `<string>`.

So first change your include to the correct file, then you need to use the `std::` scope prefix for all strings.

Answer (score 3):

For C++ you should use the according library `#include <string>` **not** `#include <string.h>` witch is a **C** library.

For variable declaration use scope

```cpp
std::string sStudentName;
```

or

```
using namespace std;
```

before the class declaration for `string` to be recognized as a type.

The first option is recommended, to know why see [Why is “using namespace std;” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: Please do not suggest to use `using namespace std;` in a header file: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/3684343

Comment: @mch, I did recommend the first option, if it exists and can be used, it's best to talk about it and say why it shouldn't be, I added the link to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

As a compromise between littering "std::" all over the file, and using the potentially dangerous "using namespace std", you can write:

```
using std::string;
```